# How To Remove Specific Rows With Consecutive Values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a Pandas dataframe, *df_next*, that is a monthly aggregation of crime type incidents for specific jurisdictions. For example, something like:

| ID | Year_Month | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AL0010000 | 1991-01 | 2024 |
| AL0010000 | 1991-02 | 3017 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| WV0550300 | 2018-11 | 30147 |
| WV0550300 | 2018-12 | 32148 |

I want to reduce the size of my dataframe by removing rows that are part of 4 months of consecutive 0 values in the 'Total' column. In other words, if a ID has reported 0 total crime for four consecutive months, I want to remove that chunk of 4 months. I want to do this for all IDs.

I've tried:

```
# Define a window size of 4
window_size = 4

# Apply a rolling window to the Total column for each ID
df_next['Total_rolling'] = df_next.groupby('ID')['Total'].rolling(window=window_size).reset_index(0, drop=True)

df_next['Remove'] = ((df_next['Total_rolling'].shift(window_size - 1) == 0) & (df_next['Total_rolling'] == 0))

# Filter out the rows where there are four consecutive 0's in the Total value for each ID
df_filtered = df_next[~df_next['Remove']]
```

However, when I check df_filtered, I still have multiple examples of IDs with four consecutive months of 0 crime totals. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Annotated Code

```
# is total zero?
m = df['Total'] == 0

# create a counter to identify different 
# blocks of consecutive zero's
b = (~m).cumsum()

# Group the rows where total is zero by `ID` and above blocks
# and transform with size to calculate the number of consecutive zeros
s = df[m].groupby(['ID', b]).transform('size')

# Drop the rows from the original dataframe where
# there are 4 or more consecutive zeros
df = df.drop(s.index[s >= 4])
```

Comment: For some reason the line `s = df[m].groupby(['ID', b]).transform('size')` generates the warning `FutureWarning: Dropping invalid columns in DataFrameGroupBy.transform is deprecated. In a future version, a TypeError will be raised. Before calling .transform, select only columns which should be valid for the function.`, followed by the error `TypeError: Transform function invalid for data types`. I can get it to work if I substitute `s = df[m].groupby(['ID', b])['Total'].transform('size')`, but remain puzzled by the error.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED:**

Here is an updated answer based on OP's comment indicating that all contiguous zeros in a streak of 4 or more should be dropped (not just the rows beginning when the streak length reaches 4):

```py
d = df.sort_values(['ID','Year_Month']).pipe(
    lambda d:d.assign(isPos=d.Total.gt(0)))[['ID','isPos']]
d['cumPos'] = d.groupby('ID').isPos.cumsum()
longZeroStreak = ( d[~d.isPos].groupby(['ID','cumPos']).isPos
    .transform(lambda s: len(s) >= 4)
    .reindex(index=df.index, fill_value=False) )
res = df[~longZeroStreak]
```

Explanation:

- Sort original dataframe by `ID, Year_Month`, create an `isPos` column with boolean indicating whether `Total` is positive, and create a `cumPos` column containing the `cumsum` of `isPos` for each `ID` group
- Group contiguous zeros by `ID` and number of preceding non-zeros and create a boolean Series `longZeroStreak` indicating whether the length of each such zero streak is `>= 4`
- Set the result to be the rows that aren't part of a streak of 4 or more zeros.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

This will do what I think your question asks:

```py
d = df.sort_values(['ID','Year_Month']).pipe(
    lambda d:d.assign(isZero=d.Total.eq(0)))[['ID','isZero']]
d['cumZeros'] = d.groupby('ID').isZero.cumsum()
d['cumZerosAtLastBreak'] = ( d.groupby('ID').cumZeros
    .transform(lambda s: s[s.eq(s.shift(1))]) )
d['cumZerosAtLastBreak'] = ( d.groupby('ID').cumZerosAtLastBreak
    .transform(lambda s:s.ffill().fillna(0, downcast='infer')) )
res = df.loc[d.cumZeros - d.cumZerosAtLastBreak < 4,:]
```

Explanation:

- Sort original dataframe by `ID, Year_Month`, add `isZero` column with boolean indicating whether `Total` is 0, and drop all columns but `ID, isZero`
- Add `cumZeros` column with `cumsum` of `isZero` for each `ID` group
- Add `cumZerosAtLastBreak` column which copies values from `cumZeros` for rows with `cumZeros == cumZeros.shift(1)`, and otherwise is NaN, for each `ID` group (this gives us the cum number of zeros, but only for rows marking the break of a zero streak)
- Update `cumZerosAtLastBreak` column by using `ffill` and `fillna(0)` (and downcast to int, just to be logically consistent) for each `ID` group
- Filter original dataframe to keep only rows with `cumZeros - cumZerosAtLastBreak < 4` (namely, rows with a zero streak length below 4).

---

Sample input:

```
           ID Year_Month  Total
0   AL0010000    2020-01      0
1   AL0010000    2020-02      0
2   AL0010000    2020-03      0
3   AL0010000    2020-04      0
4   AL0010000    2020-05    123
5   AL0010000    2020-06      0
6   AL0010000    2020-07      0
7   AL0010000    2020-08      0
8   AL0010000    2020-09      0
9   AL0010000    2020-10      0
10  AL0010000    2020-11      0
11  AL0010000    2020-12    456
12  WV0550300    2021-01      0
13  WV0550300    2021-02      0
14  WV0550300    2021-03      0
15  WV0550300    2021-04      0
16  WV0550300    2021-05    123
17  WV0550300    2021-06      0
18  WV0550300    2021-07      0
19  WV0550300    2021-08      0
20  WV0550300    2021-09      0
21  WV0550300    2021-10      0
22  WV0550300    2021-11      0
23  WV0550300    2021-12    456
```

Output:

```
           ID Year_Month  Total
0   AL0010000    2020-01      0
1   AL0010000    2020-02      0
2   AL0010000    2020-03      0
4   AL0010000    2020-05    123
5   AL0010000    2020-06      0
6   AL0010000    2020-07      0
7   AL0010000    2020-08      0
11  AL0010000    2020-12    456
12  WV0550300    2021-01      0
13  WV0550300    2021-02      0
14  WV0550300    2021-03      0
16  WV0550300    2021-05    123
17  WV0550300    2021-06      0
18  WV0550300    2021-07      0
19  WV0550300    2021-08      0
23  WV0550300    2021-12    456
```

Comment: This appears to only be removing the 4th entry in the event that 4 consecutive entries have Total value 0, instead of removing all 4.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that you want all contiguous zeros in a streak of 4 or more to be dropped (not just the rows beginning when the streak length reaches 4). I have updated my answer accordingly.